# Redefining function()

Tags: r

Works

```
c <- mean
c(1:10)
> 5.5
```

Why does this not work?

```
c <- `function`
```

Seems to be good so far

```
> c
.Primitive("function")

> `function`
.Primitive("function")
```

Nope, doesn't work

```
foo = c(...) {1}
> foo()
> Error: unexpected '{' in "foo = `c`(...){"
```

Comment: Because while `c()` is a regular function, `function()` is not. It has a special effect on parsing. Most "functions" do not have `{}` code blocks after them. `function()` is more than a function. You cannot rename it.

Comment: I think you want [this](https://github.com/wch/r-source)

Comment: You cannot use your newly defined "c" as `c(...) sum(...)` (like `function(...) sum(...)` is understood in R), but you can call it as a function, since "function" is still a function with 3 arguments: `do.call("c", list(pairlist("..." = substitute()), substitute(sum(...))))`

Comment: @rawr  ooh, that's harsh :-)

Comment: Specifically: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/gram.y#L385 which shows the legal syntax for function definitions. Its special.

Comment: Bummer that I have(?) to use `do.call` to call `c` which defeats the whole purpose of renaming `function`

Comment: To be honest, I initially tried to use something like `"c"(pairlist("..." = substitute()), substitute(sum(...)), .GlobalEnv)` (i.e. `"function"(formals, body, environment)`) but wouldn't work while wrapping it inside `do.call` (as in my comment above) does. I guess there has to be a way to make it work like this, but it seems there is no way to call "c" _exactly_ as "function".

Comment: Well, heck, if you have to define a function, you're going to lose the Golf match anyway.

Comment: Have you tried `c(x, recursive = TRUE)` ?  Sometimes that'll do it. And a read of `?Reserved` might be helpful